# Rescue SDcard spoiled by Android phone

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

My SD card is dead. It is a sandisk 32GB model (genuine one as I bought it from a well known seller). All I can see is a partition with 32MB total space. I've tried to recreate the partition table in Gparted but it does no effect (no error either).

The night before I found it spoiled, I used my android phone and plug into Windows, did some files copy/paste to transfer some data between my computers. I dont know what happened but I think my Android phone has spoiled the sd card.

What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried running `chckdsk DriveLetter: /f` and see if it fixes it? Do this in cmd.exe DriveLetter being the Letter of the SDCard. Make sure you do this in a card reader and not the phone. See if it fixes any drive errors. This will most likely fix it. As I have run the command on several different sd cards that were Currupted or similar to your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin `chckdsk` is not a command. Assuming you meant `chkdsk`, running that willy-nilly can just as well destroy something permanently. That's why the first step is usually to take a full image of the drive. But in this case it looks like the card (controller, firmware) has failed in such a way that recovery is difficult at best, if not impossible.

Comment: Hit and extra letter. But thank you for the information @Bob

Comment: Thanks guys. @Bob what can I do to fix this sd card? any hope? I do not need to recover my data.

Comment: @boh I've only ever seen this on flash drives before, and it's usually a firmware flash... you're probably better off just giving up on it. Also, you'd never really trust the card again even if it is 'fixed'.